# HTML/CSS Border not to scale with corners remaining visible

Tags: html, css

There are white corner spaces that I want to get rid of to make it fully round and professional.

I also want the black bar that is also rounded at the top to sit flush with the red top.

How can I achieve this? Please offer your solution and an associate explanation so that I can understand what is required. I'm new to HTML and CSS, so I would like to learn how this can best be completed.

```css
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: maroon;
    border-radius:30px;
}

#container nav{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    border-radius:30px;
}

#container nav #titleShown{
    width:30%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;


}


#container nav #buttons{
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius:5px;

}

#buttons #minimize, 
#buttons #maximize,
#buttons #restore, 
#buttons #close{
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'sansationregular';
    src: url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.svg#sansationregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'sansationregular';
}

h2{
    font-family: 'sansationregular';
    color: wheat;
}

button{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border : none;

}



body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family:monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/menu.css"  rel="stylesheet">
    <title id="title">Trackers</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <div id="titleShown">
            </div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="minimize">
                    <span>-</span>
                </button>
                <button id="maximize">
                    <span>□</span>
                </button>
                <button id="close">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
        <h1 class="name">Tracker(S)</h1> <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    
<script src="./init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that white gap is the background color of the `body` element. Try to change the `body`'s background color to any color other than white, then you'll see that new color. Due to the border radius which clips some space from the element region.

Comment: I am aware of this, however would prefer it it wasnt there

Comment: but that's what it should happen ! Maybe as a workaround, you can apply a `box-shadow` to the container to help distinguish it from the body and give it a feel that it's higher than the `body`  element.

Comment: Adding `background-clip: padding-box;` might do the trick also add `-webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
  -moz-background-clip:    padding;` for other browsers..  I have a feeling that the `background-color` "leaks" outside of a border it can happen when you use `border-radius`.. Those CSS properties prevent it from happening if that the problem here .

Comment: where do you want me to apply this, the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, you are very close.  Just three small changes.  The first on border radius you just want the curve on the top so 30px 30px 0px 0px will fix that.  Secondly you're pushing the nav buttons all the way to the right so give it a right margin of say 50px - you can probably use 30px.  Finally, get rid the 1px white border and repace with a hr element above and below your h1

```css
#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: maroon;
    
}

#container nav{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    border-radius:30px 30px 0px 0px;
    border-left:2px  solid white;
    border-right:2px  solid white;
    border-top:2px  solid white;
}

#container nav #titleShown{
    width:30%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;


}


#container nav #buttons{
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-right:30px;

}

#buttons #minimize, 
#buttons #maximize,
#buttons #restore, 
#buttons #close{
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'sansationregular';
    src: url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Sansation-Regular-webfont.svg#sansationregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: 0px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'sansationregular';
}

h2{
    font-family: 'sansationregular';
    color: wheat;
}

button{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border : none;

}

hr{
color:white;
}


body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family:monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/menu.css"  rel="stylesheet">
    <title id="title">Trackers</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
            <div id="titleShown">
            </div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="minimize">
                    <span>-</span>
                </button>
                <button id="maximize">
                    <span>□</span>
                </button>
                <button id="close">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
        <hr>
        <h1 class="name">Tracker(S)</h1> 
        <hr><br>
        
        </div>
    </div>

    
<script src="./init.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The white still remains on the corners(in the back) which I want to disappear, also, the margin is far too towards the left, prefered it at the edge of the right corner

Comment: 30px margin is fine, just the white corners need to go,

Comment: @HarF-kingNeat if you want the corners to be rounded there is no way to remove the white background unless you change the background of the body. Or you make the black part just a rectangle removing the radius.

Comment: see me changes, this should now be complete

Comment: this is a very good attempt, its just the corners still have the white curves

Comment: what color do you want them?

Comment: how would i add a white outline/border along the curved bit, then i can apply the background color as just the maroon

Comment: There is no way to make the corners rounder?

Comment: sure try border-radius 50px, also, recheck my answer as it should be complete and accept it if it works for you so the problem is closed out

Comment: "There is no way to make the corners rounder? " No @HarF-kingNeat still waiting on something like `border-smoothing: antialiased`

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/91#issuecomment-272241378 found this, dunno how relevant it is